# mongo db select all rows fom 2 tables based on the join condition

Tags: node.js, mongodb, aggregate, mongojs

I have 2 tables

```
 useraverage
    id
    average



 usersdetails
    id
    name
    address

output
id
name
address
average
```

i have tried lookup but its not returning the data.

```
db.userdetails.aggregate([
    {
      $lookup:
        {
          from: "useraverage",
          localField: "id",
          foreignField: "id",
          as: "useraverage"
        }
   }
    ],function (err, result) {
        console.log(result);
        res.json(result);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you using MongoDB's _id or you own ? If you're using the first option then you query should look like this :

```
    `db.userdetails.aggregate([
     {
      $lookup:
        {
          from: "useraverage",
          localField: "_id",
          foreignField: "_id",
          as: "useraverage"
        }
    },
    {$unwind : "$useraverage"},
    {$project : {
       name : 1,
       address : 1,
       average: "$useraverage.average"
       }}
     ],function (err, result) {
        console.log(result);
        res.json(result);
     });`
```

Comment: Hi thanks I have one doubt can I use a sub query  instead of user average table

Comment: I'm not sure I understand you, do you mean a subdocument? If you're using the useraverage table to just store the averages than yes I would embed that information in the userdetails table, it'll be faster performance wise.